# How to add animation in UICollection View

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am not sure, whether Question heading is explanatory. I have the images here

[image: Image number 1]

[image: Image number 2]

[image: Image number 3]

The first Image shows a UICollectionView. On the Click of any cell, it should turn into Image 2. i.e. a new popup will come up, and the Cell 3 and Cell 4 will move down. or I can say on click of cell 3, cells 5,6 will move down. How to this? How can I show this Animation?

Please help. need more info?

One Solution, could be, is to a reusableView at footer, showing and hiding it. But I need more efficeint way

I have to design this app for iPhone and iPad too

Comment: What solution did you use finally ?

Answer (score 0):

Just define multiple UICollectionViewCell classes, register them in your controller class and insert items to model on user actions. In that case red cell at "Image 2" will be just another UICollectionViewCell instance.